# Web Driver Wait is not working when page load strategy is set to none

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

**Selenium Version: 4.7.2**

I only want to wait for specific page to load so I want to disable the default behavior of driver page load strategy.

I disable it with the following code.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.page_load_strategy = "none"
```

Now for the page I want to wait for it to load, I use the following code.

```
WebDriverWait(web, seconds).until(
    lambda _: web.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"
)
```

The problem is that when `page_load_strategy` is `none`. The *waiting code* doesn't work i.e. it doesn't wait for the page `readyState` to be `complete`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/)

> The page load strategy queries the document.readyState

[image]

Seems that when you set driver capabilities / options to *ignore* web page *document.readyState* state this surpasses the code you are trying to apply here using the same parameter, the *document.readyState*

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#normal-default

Comment: @IbrahimAli Thanks for the link! I removed the first suggestion, but I still think the second (remaining) part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the *lambda* expression passed to ***`until()`*** is errorprone. You can try the following line of code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
```